# Default argument value for action in Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

Is it possible to set a default argument value for navigation action using Jetpack Navigation?

I have one `fragment` which requires argument. I want this argument's value to be `"1"` when using `navController.navigate(R.id.action1)` and `"2"` when using `navController.navigate(R.id.action2)`.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/myFragment"
    android:name="MyFragment">

    <argument android:name="action_number" />

</fragment>

<!-- action_number should be set to 1 -->
<action
    android:id="@+id/action1"
    app:destination="@id/myFragment" />

<!-- action_number should be set to 2 -->
<action
    android:id="@+id/action2"
    app:destination="@id/myFragment" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use default value in argument,

For example:-

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action1"
    app:destination="@id/myFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="value"
        android:defaultValue="1"/>
</action>ode here
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Safe Args to pass data with type safety

To add Safe Args to your project, include the following classpath in your top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

To generate Java language code suitable for Java or mixed Java and Kotlin modules, add this line to your app or module's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

Pass argumensts **Kotlin**:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
   val amountTv: EditText = view!!.findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount)
   val amount = amountTv.text.toString().toInt()
   val action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount)
   v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

**Java:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   EditText amountTv = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
   int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountTv.getText().toString());
   ConfirmationAction action =
           SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction()
   action.setAmount(amount)
   Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
}
```

In your receiving destination’s code, use the `getArguments()` method to retrieve the bundle and use its contents

**Kotlin:**

```
val args: ConfirmationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val tv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount)
    val amount = args.amount
    tv.text = amount.toString()
}
```

**Java:**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount);
    int amount = ConfirmationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getAmount();
    tv.setText(amount + "")
}
```

For more details : [Pass data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#java)

Comment: This way I have to pass the value of argument before calling `navigate` (like passing `amount` in `SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount)`). I'm looking for a solution where the value of argument is set by default - with different values for each `<action>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<argument>` tag to provide a default value inside of the `<action>` tag.

For example, your first action would become:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action1"
        app:destination="@id/myFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="action_number"
            android:defaultValue="1"/>
    </action>
```